# How to increment?

Tags: sql, sqlite

How to number each row in the sqlite column?
For example, I have coloumn with 5 empty rows. I want to each row assign number = (number of previous row) + 1.  Thus I want to get column with rows 1, 2, 3, 4, 5

Answer (score 0):

In SQLite, this is a pain.  One method is a correlated subquery.  If you have rowids turned on:

```
update t
    set col = (select count(*) from t t2 where t2.rowid <= t.rowid);
```

Otherwise, you need a column that is unique on each row.